# Creating storage for ppm/pgm image data

Tags: c++

So I'm working on a class that is supposed to read in a pgm/ppm file and eventually modify it. However, I'm still working on reading in the data. My current objective is to create storage space for the binary data. Below is my code for a function that is supposed to do that:

```
       uchar* pxm::newimg(int nrows, int ncols, int bpp)
       {
           uchar *newimage = new uchar[nrows * ncols * bpp]; 
           //uchar defined as binary data previously
           return newimage;
        }
```

I then use this in my "read" function as:

```
       img = newimg(nrows, ncols, bpp); //img declared in private section of class
       ws(myfile); //reads the newline
       myfile.read((char *) img[0], nrows * ncols * bpp); 
       //nrows, ncols, and bpp private member variables in class
       myfile.close();
```

Unfortunately, while this code compiles, it produces a segmentation fault when run. I am fairly certain my issue is in the newimg function, as I have done checks to ensure that I am reading in the file properly and setting nrows, ncols, and bpp, as well as the magicid properly. Thus I presume I am not properly initializing the array data structure. If anyone has any suggestions it would be appreciated.
Thanks,
Zeta
p.s 
If you need more details on my code, request it and I'll add more to the post.

Comment: For trivial questions like this, it's better to just ask your teacher or a TA instead of cluttering up StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(char *) img[0]` should be `img`, or `(char *) img`.

Comment: Right. The compiler assumes you know what you're doing when you recast a `uchar` to a `char*` even though one's a pointer and one isn't.